# Getting CUDALink (Toolkit 7.5) to work on Linux, Mathematica 10.0.2, GTX750

Tags: linux, cudalink

I want to make use of some CUDA functionality on my machine. It is running Gentoo Linux (64bit), Mathematica 10.0.2 on an Intel Xeon E5-1620v3 with a Geforce GTX750. So everything on the hardware/OS side should be ready for CUDA.

CUDA drivers seem to be installed properly, however `CUDAQ[]` returns `False` and `CUDAInformation[]` behaves strangely (see further below, also [this related post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/780478)). What I execute in Mathematica

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
(* no issues, seems to load fine *)

CUDAQ[]
(* False *)

CUDADriverVersion[]
(* 355.11.0 *)

CUDAResourcesInformation[]
(* {{"Name" -> "CUDAResources", "Version" -> "10.2.0.3", 
  "BuildNumber" -> "", "Qualifier" -> "LIN64", 
  "WolframVersion" -> "10.*", "SystemID" -> {"Linux-x86-64"}, 
  "Description" -> "{ToolkitVersion -> 7.5, MinimumDriver -> 300.0}", 
  "Category" -> "", "Creator" -> "", "Publisher" -> "", 
  "Support" -> "", "Internal" -> False, 
  "Location" -> 
   "/home/usersFWM/luk/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/CUDAResources-\
LIN64-10.2.0.3", "Context" -> {}, "Enabled" -> True, 
  "Loading" -> Manual, "Hash" -> "da2008695ab87c5e2e072c552dc11217"}} *)

CUDAInformation[]
( * ReplaceAll::reps: {If[Which[Developer`CheckProtectedMode[CUDAInformation],Throw[$Failed],!TrueQ[GPUTools`Internal`ValidSystemQ[]],Throw[Message[CUDAInformation::invsys,$SystemID];$Failed],<<9>>,Throw[Message[CUDAInformation::syslibfld];$Failed],True,True],Throw[Message[<<15>>::<<5>>];<<7>>],Throw[$Failed]]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >> * )

$CUDALinkLibraryPath
(* /home/usersFWM/luk/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/CUDAResources-\
LIN64-10.2.0.3/LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64 *)

$CUDALinkPath
(* /usr/local/Mathematica-10.0.2/SystemFiles/Links/CUDALink/ *)

SystemInformation[]
(* telling me under 'Links' that "CUDALink is not supported on this system." *)
```

I seriously believe that I have read all threads here about setting up CUDALink, however they do not all really match this situation (only the one I linked to previously - where currently no more information is present; I attached a screenshot of the output that was requested there below).

The first thing I tried is `CUDAResourcesUninstall[]` and `CUDAResourcesInstall[]` which also did not solve the issue. Inspired by [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90031/are-you-able-to-use-cuda-on-linux) I looked for the libraries in `/usr/lib64/`:

```
ls -l | grep "libnvidia-tls.so"
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       18 Oct 28 07:40 libnvidia-tls.so -> libnvidia-tls.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       23 Oct 28 07:40 libnvidia-tls.so.1 -> libnvidia-tls.so.355.11
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    14480 Oct 28 07:40 libnvidia-tls.so.355.11

ls -l | grep "libcuda.so"
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       12 Oct 28 07:40 libcuda.so -> libcuda.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       17 Oct 28 07:40 libcuda.so.1 -> libcuda.so.355.11
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 14548520 Oct 28 07:40 libcuda.so.355.11
```

Given that the driver version is correctly recognized as `355.11` I assume that the system variables are linked properly? Or do I nevertheless have to use `symlink` as suggested [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/92119/21606)? Usually, I would just try it, but I do not have `su` rights on my machine at work and currently there is no real system administrator - so I do not want to "waste" time of the only person left that may use `su`, that's why I want to make sure it could be the reason.

Also, if you have other suggestions or need more information, please let me know.

Here is a screenshot of output of a command requested in the thread linked first.
[image]

### Update

After a very long waiting period I have finally received something like a "final" statemet from support. Unfortunately, it seems they are unable to track down the issue:

> I apologize for the long response time. Unfortunately, I've not been
>   able to get any further useful help from our developers for your issue
>   and there is nothing more that I can do to assist you. I have filed a
>   suggestion on your behalf to look into the underlying cause of the
>   issue.

Comment: If people vote to close, would they please report why? This is nothing that has been reported on this site as far as I could see and also at least one more person seems to have this issue, so it cannot be unique to my machine.

Comment: The two close votes are for the reason "The answer to this question requires either advice from Wolfram support or the services of a professional consultant."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for clarification! In fact, I got into contact with support today and will report back if they could resolve the issue

Comment: Please remember to self-answer if you get a solution, or even an explanation.  If you wish to but people have closed your question at that time, use a moderator flag and notify me and I'll reopen it so you can post.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Will do so!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have contacted support multiple times after they sent the issue to the developers. Every time someone promised to send me an update about what has been found out. Unfortunately, no-one has ever written me an email or whatsoever... Do you have any tip how to make them get into contact with me? Quite disappointing that Wolfram stays completely quite here, even after four months :-(

Comment: Sorry, I have no tips for getting Support to answer.  It is probably a tricky issue and the persons involved may be overworked.  Getting more attention here would probably help, but if the problem is not experienced by many that is likely not going to happen.  :-/